# Nifi JoltTransform : explode json arrays while keeping all root attributes

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a scenario very similar to what's described [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NiFi-Explode-a-JSON-array-while-keeping-root-level-fields/td-p/188384) : I need to flatten a json with several nested arrays on Nifi, while keeping all root level attributes.

The following spec works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid having to write each root level attribute? The json files I need to transform have many root level attributes, as well as many nested arrays, so it's not very convenient. Plus the json schema might change over time or from file to file, so having to write each attribute makes it more prone to human errors.

Working spec looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "nested_1": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,root_attribute)": "[&3].[&1].root_attribute",
            "*": "[&3].[&1].&2\\.&"
          }
        },
        "nested_2": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,root_attribute)": "[&3].[&1].root_attribute",
            "*": "[&3].[&1].&2\\.&"
          }
        }
     }
]
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way than writing `"@(2,root_attribute)": "[&3].[&1].root_attribute"` for each root level attribute, for each nested array?

I tried playing with the `&` and `@` wildcards, but to no avail.